# What to include when putting SVG code inline into an HTML5 document

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

I am trying to insert an SVG I coded / drew into an HTML5 document and I was wondering what needed to go along with the SVG code inside the document.

After reading some tutorials, I learned it is best to place the  in a container with set dimensions. Then give its child, the svg tag, the proper version of the syntax attribute, baseProfile attribute, xmlns attribute, and a height and width of 100%.

Then, put the svg code, the definitions, paths, etc, as the children of the SVG element.

Am I missing anything or is anything I have not required?

Also, should I add the following before the  tag or is it just required in stand-alone svg documents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need xmlns in html5. As you suspected, DOCTYPE and xml version are for standalone files.

Comment: Ah, so as long as I have the HTML5 Doctype, I can get rid of the xmlns attribute?